# Javascript functions are being called all at once

Tags: javascript, php

The purpose of my code is to randomly display four icons and depending on which one the user clicks on, a small amount of text will be appended to a text file. My problem is that, after an icon is clicked on, all four of the functions are called which writes to the txt file four times. How can I get it so that only the correctly corresponding function is called.

```
    <div style="text-align:center" "padding-left: 60px">
        <form action="(im hiding the URL)construct/index.html" id="formid" onclick= function() {myFunction()}>
            <form>

            </form>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("icon_1.png").onclick = function writeTo1(){
            <?php
                $file = fopen("icon_select.txt","a");
                echo fwrite($file,"-Icon 1-");
                fclose($file);
            ?>  
        }
        document.getElementById("icon_2.png").onclick = function writeTo2(){
            <?php
                $file = fopen("icon_select.txt","a");
                echo fwrite($file,"-Icon 2-");
                fclose($file);
            ?>  
        }
        document.getElementById("icon_3.png").onclick = function writeTo3(){
            <?php
                $file = fopen("icon_select.txt","a");
                echo fwrite($file,"-Icon 3-");
                fclose($file);
            ?>  
        }
        document.getElementById("icon_4.png").onclick = function writeTo4(){
            <?php
                $file = fopen("icon_select.txt","a");
                echo fwrite($file,"-Icon 4-");
                fclose($file);
            ?>  
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: you cannot mix the php with the javascript. javascript execute in the browser and the php execute on the server

Comment: do you know of a good way I can solve this issue then? @FaizRasool

Comment: @FaizRasool Of course you can :)

Comment: What you are looking to do will likely involve an additional php file that the javascript will 'post' to, which will handle the file operations.  Right now, every time you refresh this page (regardless of whether you click the icons) all 4 file operations are executed.  Everything within `<?php ?>` will execute on the server side prior to any document interaction.

Comment: @bub in this situation every time when he hit refresh without even calling the javascript function the php execute the code

Comment: @SuperJer If I create another php file, in the same directory on the server, will I be able to call functions that exist in the separate php files from one-another? ie: call writeto1() from a separate php file?

Comment: @Breezy:  Yes, in a way.  They don't need to be in the same folder, and it's not likely how you think.  In order for a page to run responsively the way it seems you are expecting it to, you'll need to use AJAX.  [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp) is not a programming language, but rather a means of interfacing the browser scripts with the server scripts.  A StackOverflow answer is not an adequate place to teach AJAX, but w3schools is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the 4 bits of PHP are running when the page is requested, and therefore adding to the text file at that time. Then the functions are empty when the JavaScript runs so it has no effect. Check the page source in the browser to see what the functions look like to the browser and after page load but before clicking on an icon check to see if the text has been added to the file.